# Developing for SharePoint 2013 using Visual Studio 2012 offline installer

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am behind a corporate firewall and the company I work for has VS 2012 Ultimate. I want to start developing for SharePoint 2013 using VS 2012. I found out later that the default installation does not include project templates for SP 2013, but requires to install "Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012" that can be found @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/apps/fp123627 .

This tool is installed through Web Platform installer. The MS WebPi has does not work where proxy authentication is required and throws an error.

Is there any offline installer for "Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012" ?

Answer (score 2):

Here links provide for this download

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/appsforsharepoint/thread/3da6b156-f1e0-45e6-bcd3-dfe7afa3b11a/